# interpolation in multiobjective optimization of linear functions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, normed-spaces, interpolation

I seek to find a matrix $\mathbf{X}$ which minimizes

$g(||\mathbf{A}_1-\mathbf{XB}_1||_F, ||\mathbf{A}_2-\mathbf{XB}_2||_F)$,

where $g$ is some convenient norm (e.g. $L^1$-norm, $L^2$-norm or $L^\infty$-norm).

Suppose, it is hard to minimize $g$ directly, but easy to find $\mathbf{X}_1$ which minimizes $||\mathbf{A}_1-\mathbf{XB}_1||_F$ and, separately, also easy to find $\mathbf{X}_2$ which minimizes $||\mathbf{A}_2-\mathbf{XB}_2||_F$.

In this context, is it possible to compute an interpolation $\mathbf{X}_3 = f(\mathbf{X}_1, \mathbf{X}_2)$, such that $\mathbf{X}_3$ could be shown to minimize $g$.

If so, what would the interpolation function $f(\mathbf{X}_1, \mathbf{X}_2)$ be? I am looking for a principled solution, rather than for a heuristic which seems to work.

Comment: Why should you expect that there is any $X$ which simultaneously (i.e., separately) minimizes both? How about minimizing a weighted sum of the two norms, or minimize a weighted sum of the squares of the two norms, or minimize one of the norms subject to an upper bound on the other norm? For the latter formulation, you could use the results of solving the norm minimization problems individually to guide you in the selection of upper bounds for the constraints (or do it parametrically to get an efficient frontier).

Comment: The short answer is no.

Comment: @Mark, thank you for your comment. I was in fact seeking to minimize some sum of the norms, and have rephrased the question in order to clarify this (I omitted the weights in the sum, without loss of generality). If you could point to a source which describes the selection of upper bounds, this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Of course, if you were willing to minimize the sum of the *squares* of the norms, then your problem would be equivalent to minimizing a single norm, since $$\|A_1-XB_1\|_F^2 + \|A_2-XB_2\|_F^2 = \|\begin{bmatrix} A_1 & A_2 \end{bmatrix} - X \begin{bmatrix} B_1 & B_2 \end{bmatrix}\|_F^2$$

Comment: @Michael, it is much harder to minimize the sum of squares of the norms numerically, the problem does not scale well.

Comment: I don't get that. What algorithm are you using to find $X_1$ and $X_2$, that cannot be applied to the larger problem?

Comment: Consider these notes on decomposition methods [PDF](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee392o/decomposition.pdf).

Comment: To write the sum of the squares of the norms, I need to split $A_1$, $A_2$, $X$, $B_1$ and $B_2$ into submatrices, and then arrange the submatrices into three block-diagonal matrices $A_\textrm{block}$, $X_\textrm{block}$, and $B_\textrm{block}$. This does not scale well memory-wise.

Comment: Great, thanks for the notes! I will have a look.

Comment: @Akim, no, you don't have to do that. I just showed you in the above comment that you just stack the $A$ and $B$ matrices horizontally and solve the single problem.

Comment: The first instance cannot happen. Since $X$ is compatible with left-multiplication on both $B_1$ and $B_2$, the the horizontal concatenation I showed you will _always_ work. The second example is simply a different problem and not relevant to your question.

Comment: How about this case:
$A_1 (a, b), X (a, k), B_1 (k, b), A_2 (a, c), X (a, k), B_2 (k, c)$

Comment: Yes, that case works just fine with horizontal concatenation.